# jQuery - .slideUp() not works after event.stopPropagation();

Tags: jquery, effects, slideup, stoppropagation

I have a problem with event.stopPropagation (), in my code: (! When put. Show () after this event works perfectly, however, as put. SlideUp () does not work! 
What I truly want is when the user click the search bar and the same body and the chat is hidden, it must appear with the effect slideUp (), If I remove the stopPropagation, clicking in the search bar of your body chat also disappear as this within the event of the div.

See jsfiddle [**Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/Igaojsfiddle/GrwUe/1/)

```
$(".chatHeader").on('click', function() {
       $('.chatBody').slideToggle();
    });


    $('#searchText').click(function(e) {
      event.stopPropagation();    
      $('.chatBody').show();
        // $('.chatBody').slideUp(); not works
    });
```

Who can help me with this, I would be very grateful for your time invested on it!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one is tricky. Read that :

*"Hide the matched elements with a sliding motion."*

This is taken from the jquery doc of slideUp: http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/

In other word, you need to use `slideDown()` if you want the window to show.

*"Display the matched elements with a sliding motion."*

http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GrwUe/3/)**

Comment: Yes this is the same friend! I'm out of time to read through the documentation, it never even crossed my mind, even the syntax! Thank you my friend worked perfectly! :) -Cheers

Answer (score 0):

is there any specific reason you use event.stopPropagation() ? that would block the event from bubbling up.. Try event.preventDefault();

Comment: Why do not you want that when the user clicks on the search box trigger the event to hide the body of the chat ('. ChatBody'). I put this in code, see how it was [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Igaojsfiddle/GrwUe/2/)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$(".chatHeader").not('#searchText').on('click', function() { ...
```

ive seen a conflict between slideUp and slideToggle

Comment: Ive no time to test  but try : $(".chatHeader:not(#searchText)");

Comment: Hi friend, had tried that and it does not work! (The way that events are fired) - Thank you again.

Comment: ok , try with $('.chatBody').stop(); $('.chatBody').slideUp();